# ajax jquery post successfully returns result in firefox but simple variables are empty elsewhere

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, json, post

Got a problem that has seriously caused some annoyance and haven't been able to find a solution to this specific problem. I'm using the ajax post with json to my webservice and then using a returned value. Everything works as expected in firefox, but not elsewhere (ie, chrome, safari).

In the other browsers it will however always work perfectly if I'm returning more complex values (such as my own objects) but more standard variables (strings, bool, int[] etc) will get lost on the way and returned response data will be empty (although everything successful til that point). So everything works except the returned value in non-ff is null unless custom objects.

Two interesting notes:

1. Removing the contentType specification completely does make it successfully return simple variables although call will fail otherwise. Could possibly play around with this and make it work although problems will occur when returning empty lists and such. And not really a proper solution either.
2. Using fiddler does not catch the I.E post requests, only ff. in ff it gives the following error (evne though result later is ok):
   "Content-Length mismatch: Response Header claimed  1767884 bytes, but server sent 1772317 bytes."

pretty standard postmethod (been playing around with different arguments such as cache etc to no avail):

```
/* Excutes a remote method */
function executeMethod(location, methodName, methodArguments, onSuccess, onFail) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: location + "/" + methodName,
    data: methodArguments,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: onSuccess,
    error: onFail
  });
}
```

Webservice method:

```
namespace Domain1.ClientServices
{
  [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
  [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]

  public class AjaxService 
{
....
[OperationContract]
    public string PrintTransportNote(int meansOfTransport, int deliveryId)
    {
        return "string1";
    }
}
}
```

sidenote, I am using third party provider telerik if that may be cause of any concern.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this issue for over 9 hours until I found this:

http://blogs.planetsoftware.com.au/paul/archive/2010/06/25/radcompression-module-and-ria.aspx

Apparently you need to disable the "RadCompression" module when working in the development webserver.  You do not need to do this for IIS however the compression module works correctly.